Mixed compose XML layout using UI androidTest unable to move between objects
We are slowly adding Compose to our app one page/fragment at a time.  I have a page that is mostly compose except the Top Bar.  In my androidTest UI test I go from home to my second page which is all compose except the TopBar with on Menuitem.  In my code I have espresso onViews then when I get to the compose parts I use the composeRule.apply to do multiple compose actions.  This all works until I want to hit the Menu button then try and go back to one item in the compose layout.  When I do I always get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compose hierarchies found in the app"
@get:Rule
var composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

@Test
fun clickResetMenuButton() {
    startHome()

    clickToSecondPageMixedComposeView()

    composeRule.apply {
        waitUntilExists(hasText("Field1"), 5000)
        onNodeWithText("Field1").performClick()
        waitUntilExists(hasText("Field2"), 5000)
        onNodeWithText("Field2").performClick()

        pressBackUnconditionally()
        // wait for view to settle so I can dump it
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        device.dumpWindowHierarchy(System.out as OutputStream)
        // here I dump the window hierarchy and the menu item does not show 
        // I've tried all methods onView, doOnview, waitForView isRoot...
        // So I just click on it using coordinates
        device.click(100, 100)

        // blows up here 
        waitUntilExists(hasTestTag("confirmButton"), 5000)
        onNodeWithTag("confirmButton").performClick()
        waitForDoesNotExist(hasTestTag("confirmButton"), 5000)
    }
}

It's almost as if the composeRule nulls out once I click outside the compose fields.  I have even noticed in LayoutInspector that the Top Bar does not show a layout only the compose section.
